# Array not loading for v-for

Tags: arrays, for-loop, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to loop through a set of users from jsonplaceholder API.

Here is my Vue component:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#vue-app",
  data: {
    name: "dani",
    thumbnail: '',
    users: []
  },
  beforeMount() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(function (response) {
        this.users = response.data
        console.log("users: ", this.users[0])
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
})
```

And here is the `vue-app` div in HTML page:

```
<div id="vue-app">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4" v-for="user in users">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{ user.name }}</h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{ user.email }}</p>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Loop doesn't pulls and displays anything. How to load `users` array to `v-for` properly?

Here is the JSFiddle for the same : https://jsfiddle.net/danimvijay/9gupydws/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in your function is undefined. In vue life cycle methods, `created`, `mounted`..., Vue has already bound `this` instance for us. But in function in `axios.get().then(function())`, `this` is not bound.

You might want to do

```
  beforeMount() {
    console.log('Before mount')
    const vm = this
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(function (response) {
        vm.users = response.data
        console.log("users: ", vm.users[0])
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        throw error
      })
  }
```

or you can use es6 syntax

```
 beforeMount() {
    console.log('Before mount')
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then((response) => {
        this.users = response.data
        console.log("users: ", this.users[0])
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        throw error
      })
  }
```

In arrow function, `this` is bound to lexical context, which mean it's same with `this` in created

Comment: It works. Can you explain why `this` behaved like this?

Comment: I updated my answer